# Is there a canonical webrtc peer URL format?

Tags: url, webrtc

Is there a canonical format for encoding all the information needed to reach a WebRTC peer in a URL? Like let's say I want to reach a peer and do not know the STUN/TURN servers or anything. Is there any standard format for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing users is part of signaling which is declared [out of scope](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#introduction) in the specification.